# Mysql в рhp как настроить?

Tags: php, mysql, настройка

как настроить и записать что-либо в базу данных ? Собсно в пхп 2016

Comment: вы хоть одну документацию открывали? Примеров в нашей необъятной сети бесконечность+1. Любой поисковик найдет для вас материал.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно поднять MySQL сервер, для начала. Скачать можно от [сюда](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/5.7.html).

После, можно пользоваться БД. Вот [пример](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysql.examples-basic.php) кода:

```
<?php
// Соединяемся, выбираем базу данных
$link = mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')
    or die('Не удалось соединиться: ' . mysql_error());
echo 'Соединение успешно установлено';
mysql_select_db('my_database') or die('Не удалось выбрать базу данных');

// Выполняем SQL-запрос
$query = 'SELECT * FROM my_table';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Запрос не удался: ' . mysql_error());

// Выводим результаты в html
echo "<table>\n";
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    foreach ($line as $col_value) {
        echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }
    echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

// Освобождаем память от результата
mysql_free_result($result);

// Закрываем соединение
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Как уже заметили в комментариях, mysql_* функции уже не желательно использовать в PHP. Сейчас следует использовать функции [MySQLi](https://habrahabr.ru/post/119294/):

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* проверяем соединение */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Ошибка соединения: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$city = "Ярославль";

/* создаем подготовленное выражение */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {

    /* связываем параметр */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);

    /* исполняем запрос */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* прикрепляем результаты*/
    $stmt->bind_result($district);

    /* выбираем значение */
    $stmt->fetch();

    printf("%s находится в %s\n", $city, $district);

    $stmt->close();
}

/* закрываем соединение */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: если вы не следили за ситуацией последние несколько лет, то использование функций семейства `mysql_*` уже запрещено

Comment: С одной стороны вроде как ответ дан, даже подробный, заслуживает плюса. С другой стороны, действительно, mysql уже черт знает сколько времени как deprecated, а в PHP7 так вообще отсутствует - это явный минус. Перепишите на использование mysqli (и лучше в ООП стиле)